# how to make the record auto increment and filled in excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

There is a column like the above,now, i want to add some records as the following:

```
20120210
20120211
20120212
20120213
......
```

Is there a way to make them auto increment and filled with a batch. thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. 20120209, 20120210 in two rows
2. select both
3. drag downward by click in right down of selection